# Find directories case insensitively

Tags: find, case-sensitivity

I'm trying to put together a `find` command to list directories under `/home` with names that start with `adm_` but I need the `find` to be case insensitive (rhel v7).  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `-iname` option is what you are looking for.

`find /home -iname 'adm_*'`

Add `-type d` to limit to directories.

`find /home -iname 'adm_*' -type d`

Comment: Thanks for this, I used:

cd /home; find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -iname 'adm*'

Comment: `find *` isn't a good usage since "*" will be interpreted by bash and replaced by every non-hidden file in your home directory... so if the directory you're looking for is into an hidden directory (ie: `.config`) you won't see it. The path isn't mandatory so `find -maxdepth 0 -typed d -iname "adm*"` would be enought

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways depending on what you want to do with the names that match the pattern.

If you just want to print them, use `-iname` rather than `-name` with `find` on your Linux system:

```
find /home -type d -iname 'adm_*'
```

To use them for something with `find`:

```
find /home -type d -iname 'adm_*' -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        # use "$dirpath" here
    done' sh {} +
```

This would apply the in-line shell script to all directories matching the pattern case insensitively anywhere in or under `/home`.

If you want to restrict the search to only `/home` (not recursively), also insert `-maxdepth 1` after the search path (before any action).

You also have the option to glob them directly in the shell.  Assuming you are using `bash`, just set the `nocaseglob` shell option:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
printf '%s\n' /home/adm_*/
```

This would print out all the pathnames of directories in `/home` matching the pattern case insensitively.  The trailing `/` makes sure that we only ever match directories.

To also search inside subdirectories, additionally set the `globstar` option and use `**`:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob globstar
printf '%s\n' /home/**/adm_*/
```

You may obviously use this directly in a loop:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob globstar dotglob nullglob
for dirpath in /home/**/adm_*/; do
    # use "$dirpath" here
done
```

The `dotglob` option makes globbing patterns match hidden names (just like `find` would do), and `nullglob` makes sure that the pattern is removed completely if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

With `find` implementations that don't support the non-standard `-iname` extension, you can use:

```
find /home -name '[aA][dD][mM]_*' -type d
```

With some `find` implementations including GNU `find` as found on RHEL, that will not include files whose name contains sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the current locale. Doing:

```
LC_ALL=C find /home -name '[aA][dD][mM]_*' -type d
```

Would address that as in the C locale, all single byte values form one valid character each. (and `a`, `A`, `d`, `D`, `m`, `M`, `_` are all part of the portable charset so generally their encoding is invariant among all locales on the system).

For the standard equivalent of GNU's `-maxdepth 1` you'd do:

```
LC_ALL=C find /home/. ! -name . -prune -name '[aA][dD][mM]_*' -type d
```

(technically, that's more like `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` or FreeBSD's `-depth 1 -prune` which is in fact closer to what you need (here depth 0 (`.`) which you don't want is otherwise only excluded because it doesn't match that pattern)).